# How is the face for a tree graph bounded by any sides at all? (Graph theory)

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, plane-geometry, planar-graphs

I have learnt that every face in a planar graph has sides, and that sides are edges which bound the face clockwise. I am very confused about a few things regarding sides:

1. I am not seeing how the single infinite face for a tree graph is bounded by any edges at all- how can an infinite region be bounded, which would imply it is finite?
2. I am not seeing why we would count an edge as being in 2 different sides for a undirected tree graph- how does this edge constitute 2 different sides in the boundary? Is it because an undirected graph has 2 directed edges for each edge? So if we replaced every undirected edge in nthe undirected tree graph with a directed edge, we would wouldn't count these edges twice in the degree of the single face?
3. What does it mean for the sides to bound the face "clockwise"? What does clockwise mean here? I am not seeing how this notion is relevant as to the definition of a side.

EDIT- it appears the notion of how many sides a face has is related to the notion of the degree of a face, and the latter notion is used instead of the former in certain contexts- so for those who are unfamiliar with the definition I presented, this is how it related to the seemingly more common notion of degree of a face.

Comment: see   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apeirogon

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to understand the terminology, if you think of adding a point at infinity and using the [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) to view the graph as embedded in a sphere rather than the plane. Then the infinite face becomes a finite space that contains the point at infinity. If there are edges which have that face on both sides (as they all will in a tree) then that edge will appear twice when you work around the edges of that face.

As a minimalist example, a graph comprising just a single edge has as its exterior a face that you can think of as a disc with the perimeter divided into two semi-circles corresponding to the two sides of the edge. (Think of cutting a slit in a basketball.)

Note that this only works for connected graphs that have at least one edge.